# Can't paste files to GoPro from KDE Manjaro

Tags: filesystems, manjaro, readonly

I'm trying to update my GoPro Hero 3 by copying the update file to the gopro as per the instructions.  However, It's telling me that it's a read-only filesystem:

```
cp ~/Downloads/UPDATE.zip /run/media/username/0123-4567/
cp: cannot create regular file '/run/media/username/0123-4567/UPDATE.zip': Read-only file system
```

I've already tried formatting the SD card from the settings on the device and I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: How did you mount it? Can you remount it in `rw` mode?

Comment: $ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdf1 /run/media/username/0123-4567
mount: /run/media/username/0123-4567: cannot remount /dev/sdf1 read-write, is write-protected.

Comment: One thing could be that it is locked due to a sloppy unmount. What happens when you run a check (`fsck`) on it? Just to be sure: the hardware switch on the SD card is in the right position?